# Как откинуть дробную часть до сотых?

Tags: php

```
1,515 = 1,51
3,999 = 3,99
3,03 = 3,03
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function customRound($i) {

    $i *= 100;
    $i = floor($i);
    return $i / 100;
}
```

Comment: А за что минус? Правильный ответ же (для положительных `$i`).

Answer (score 1):

Это функция окрулгления
http://www.php.su/functions/?round

Comment: Еще раз говорю, не округлить, а отбросить

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$val *= 100;
if ($val >= 0)
    $val = floor($val);
else
    $val = ceil($val);
$val /= 100;
```

Учтите, однако, что десятичные дроби в памяти компьютера представляются неточно.

Comment: Только я бы сократил до примерно такого:

    $val *= 100;
    $val = ($val >= 0 ? floor($val) : ceil($val)) / 100;

Answer (score 1):

Неделя идиотских преобразований объявляется открытой. C-замашки.

```
function mega($num) {
    $data = sscanf($num, "%d,%s");
    return sprintf("%d,%.2s",$data[0],$data[1]);
}
```

http://ideone.com/225a1a

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = "1,515";
$num = substr($num, 0, -1);

echo $num; // 1,51
```

Comment: @mountpoint будьте внимательны...

    $num="1,5"

Comment: @eicto, ну так автор указал с запятой, я и заключил число в кавычки. или я вас не понял?

Comment: http://ideone.com/HrIlE1

Comment: @eicto, http://pastebin.com/u6YLQGT1 так работает с любыми числами. Естественно этот код предназначен для тех чисел, которые содержат запятую, а не точку

Answer (score 0):

`$sum *= 100;
$ArrTemp = split ("[\,]", $sum);
$sum = $ArrTemp['0'] / 100;`

Answer (score -2):

В вашей постановке задачи только анализом строки, например так:

```
preg_replace("/^(.*[,\.]\d{0,2}).*$/","$1","$num");
```

http://ideone.com/SkPMB2